# Change value based on an "if then" statement in r

Tags: r

I have a data set with this set up:

| id | color |
| --- | --- |
| a | blue |
| a | blue |
| a | blue |
| a | blue |
| b | green |
| b | green |

I would like to rename color based on number of id entries. For example, if n > 3, then pink. I would like the output to look like this:

| id | color |
| --- | --- |
| a | pink |
| a | pink |
| a | pink |
| a | pink |
| b | green |
| b | green |

I have primarily been using "ready made" codes, if you will, and have just started attempting to write my own codes to accomplish things, albeit fairly unsuccessfully. This is the code I have attempted to write, but alas, it doesn't work:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% if(n() > 3){print("pink")}
```

If it is pertinent, color is a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(n() > 3, "pink", color)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  id    color
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     pink 
2 a     pink 
3 a     pink 
4 a     pink 
5 b     green
6 b     green
```

If there are more colors to add based on a count, use `case_when` instead:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(n() > 1 & n() <= 3 ~ "brown",
                           n() > 3 ~ "pink",
                           TRUE ~ color)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This code works when applied to the example, but when I apply it to my own dataset, I get this error message: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `color`.
i `color= ifelse(n() >3, "pink", color)`.
x `color` must return compatible vectors across groups
i Result type for group 1 (color = blue): <integer>.
i Result type for group 2 (color = green): <character>. I don't understand this message. The color column is a factor.

Comment: @Chullah A factor is in fact an integer vector just relabeled. Is "pink" a new color or is it an already existing color?

Comment: It would be new.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `if/else` within in the `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(color = if(n() > 3) "pink" else color) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  id    color
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     pink 
2 a     pink 
3 a     pink 
4 a     pink 
5 b     green
6 b     green
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$color[with(df, id %in% names(which(table(id) > 3)))] <- "pink"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), color = c("blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```